# while coding for a csv file: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, csv, valueerror

Given a csv file. I want the variable good_words to have all the words that are there in the CleanedText column. But it shows the following error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The CleanedText column has all the words that are obtained after removing the stopwords using nltk.

```
good_words = []
if edata3['class']=='good':
    good_words = edata3.loc[0: , 'CleanedText']
```

The code block before it is:

```
import os
if os.path.isfile(r'/Users/vivekbhadula/study/cleaned_final.db'):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(r'/Users/vivekbhadula/study/cleaned_final.db')
    final = edata2['CleanedText']
    edata3 = edata2.copy()
    edata3.append(final)
else:
    print('Please run the above cell')
```

The output of edata3.head() is :

```
**Clothing ID|| Age ||Title ||         Review_Text||    Rating||            Recommended_IND      ||   Positive_Feedback_Count ||    Division_Name|| Department_Name ||Class_Name||  class|| CleanedText**
2   1077||  60  ||Some major design flaws ||    I had such high hopes for this dress and reall...   ||3 ||0  ||0    ||General|| Dresses ||Dresses|| bad high hope dress realli want work initi order p...
3   1049    50  My favorite buy!    I love, love, love this jumpsuit. it's fun, fl...   5   1   0   General Petite  Bottoms Pants   good    love love love jumpsuit fun flirti everi time ...
4   847     47  Flattering shirt    This shirt is very flattering to all due to th...   5   1   6   General Tops    Blouses good    shirt flatter due adjust front tie perfect len...
5   1080    49  Not for the very petite I love tracy reese dresses, but this one is no...   2   0   4   General Dresses Dresses bad love traci rees dress one petit feet tall usua...
6   858     39  Cagrcoal shimmer fun    I aded this in my basket at hte last mintue to...   5   1   1   General Petite  Tops    Knits   good    ade basket hte last mintu see would look like ...
```

Comment: you are comparing entire column with single value `edata3['class']=='good'`

Comment: yes. there is another column named class that has values good or bad only. so on that basis i want to add words where the class column shows good to this variable good_words

Comment: are you using pandas?

Comment: yes using pandas

Comment: post the expected output and sample data in `edata3`

Comment: on the basis of those words that are stored in good_words, i want to do barplot to find which words occur the maximum number of times

Comment: Is edata3 dataframe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213481/discussion-between-vivek-bhadula-and-komatiraju032).

Answer (score 0):

good_words = ' '.join([text for text in edata3[edata3['class']=='good']['CleanedText']])

This worked.